# GitHub Actions, detect changes in submodule

Tags: git, github, github-actions, building-github-actions

I have two repositories A and B, both hosted on GitHub.

- Repo A is static site generator code.
- Repo B is bunch of text files.

They have to stay separate. I want to rebuild repo A, each time repo B receives an update. It has to work using GitHub Actions only. I'd prefer if repo B would stay action-less, i.e. no CI/CD attached to that repo (I want it to store only files). I was thinking maybe I can make it work using git submodules? Repo B would be a submodule within Repo A. Is it possible to build GH action within repo A, to detect changes in repo B and pull from there?

*edit:* Repo A is Static-site generator(`nextjs`) I'm intending to share with public. Repo B is full of text files(`org-roam`) which a user brings with themselves. Together they build a personal wiki website. I'd want to minimize the configuration hassle - that's why I want to have all CI/CD and code encapsulated in Repo A, so the user could just fork it, and plug-and-play it with their knowledge base repository (repo B). Having intertwined GitHub Actions between two repositories seems not ideal - that's why I'm searching for better solution

Comment: You can use a `repository_dispatch` action on a workflow from the repo B (that will be updated) to trigger another workflow on repo A. Here is a good reference to start using it: https://blog.marcnuri.com/triggering-github-actions-across-different-repositories/ (I've implemented it this week and it worked great!)

Comment: GuiFalourd's solution is the best way imo. If you really want to keep B action-less, you could run an action in repo A on a schedule and check for changes.

Comment: Thanks @GuiFalourd and @riQQ ! Yes, `schedule (cron)` GA seems to be the only way to do it if I'd want to encapsulate all CI/CD related steps in repo A, and I'm not fond of this solution (a lot of waste). One thing I'm also considering is setting up `webhooks` inside repo B, which would trigger repo A via `repository_dispatch`. Would something like that work? Are there any drawbacks in comparison to having `GA` in both repositories? I updated the question for complete the picture of my situation. My feeling is webhooks would be a lil bit simpler to setup for end user.

Comment: nope - webhooks solution does not seem to be possible, because I can't really modify/shape the request that's being sent from repo B

Comment: It would probably be easier to have everything in the same repo so anybody could fork it and have all datas at their disposition. But I understand your point in keeping separated what would be commum to everyone. In that case I still think repository_dispatch will be better as everyone will be able to fetch the repo when updated anyway. Moreover, you can send a body with the dispatches requests if you want to send specific datas from one repo to the other (it is explained in the link I shared in the first comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @GuiFalourd and @riQQ , I was able to put together proof-of-concept set of repositories

- https://github.com/smallstepman/github-actions-submodule-test-parent
- https://github.com/smallstepman/github-actions-submodule-test-child

Both repo share same [GitHub Personal Access Token](https://github.com/settings/tokens). To fill the blanks from the blog.marcnuri.com guide, here is minimal set of permissions required to make this work (given both repositories are public, otherwise you need `repo` permission:
[image]

Comment: why did you deleted these repositories? I really would like to know how you solved this problem.

Comment: my apologies @David, I changed visibility back to public

Comment: Cute drawings, the only problem is that you are sending your access token to an external repository, that's NOT so cute. I suggest modifying the comment about repository permissions in this answer emphasizing this behavior.